# Querying for records with parameters depending upon previous dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

My table are in the form of :

```
Id, Date, Open,High,Low,Close,VOlume,OI
```

I am using MS Access, and I need to query like this:

```
Select those dates(D), where Close on D-2> D-3 and D-1>D-2
```

So, how do I form a query, with this? In general, you can think of it as a query with its parameters on previous records.

Soham

Comment: What are D-1, D-2 etc supoosed to be?

Comment: WHERE `(the value of Close 2 days ago) is greater than (the value of Close 3 days ago)` AND `(the value of Close 1 day ago) is greater than (the value of Close 2 days ago)`

Comment: Although you hve an Id column, are we able to assume that ther eis only ever one record per date?  Also, is the Id value related to the date?  (Yesterday's ID is always one less than Today's ID?)

Comment: @Dems No the id is non unique number, the only thing unique here is Date for a particular id you can say. i.e for a Particular ID, a Date is unique. Anyway, you just have to work with the dates. I dont know , if I answered your question

Comment: So when I look for (D-1), (D-2) and (D-3), I should also ensure that the ID values are the same?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT
  [Today].*
FROM
  (
    (
      MyTable AS [Today]
    INNER JOIN
      MyTable AS [TodayMinus1]
        ON  [TodayMinus1].Date = DATEADD("d", -1, [Today].Date)
        AND [TodayMinus1].ID   = [Today].ID
    )
  INNER JOIN
    MyTable AS [TodayMinus2]
      ON  [TodayMinus2].Date = DATEADD("d", -2, [Today].Date)
      AND [TodayMinus2].ID   = [Today].ID
  )
INNER JOIN
  MyTable AS [TodayMinus3]
    ON  [TodayMinus3].Date = DATEADD("d", -3, [Today].Date)
    AND [TodayMinus3].ID   = [Today].ID
WHERE
      [TodayMinus1].Close > [TodayMinus2].Close
  AND [TodayMinus2].Close > [TodayMinus3].Close
```

**EDIT** Note to elaborate on the use of three joins.

Systems like SAS operate as explicit loops where you are able to base a calculation on the values or results obtained from previous itterations of the loop.

SQL, however, is expressed as Sets rather than loops, and then the optimiser estimates the most algorithmically efficient way to accomplish that logic.  This set based expression, however, traditionally means that you can't say "three records ago" as the set doesn't have an explicit order, or an order it is processed in (parallelism may mean it's processed in chuncks, index may mean it's processed in different orders, etc, etc).

This means that you need a set based mechanism for obtaining the records you want to compare.  In this case, if you want to compare "today" with "yesterday", each on of those is a set which you join together before comparing.  You have a total of 4 different days, so 4 different sets to join together for comparison.  In a harsh sense, that's just how a relational database's set based expression works...

ANSI-SQL does now, however, include windowing functions such as LAG that allow a set based notation for what you desire.  It is not yet widely implemented for a variety of reasons.  As ACCESS is a light-weight database (compared with MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc) I wouldn't expect leading edge functionality.

Comment: Damn, I cant believe it, I have to do an INNER JOIN for this. I thought it was pretty simple query. Select those dates, where Close 2 days back > Close 3 days back and Close 1 day back>Close 2 days back. In general, its, select those dates, where Close is rising continuously for last 2 days. How hard could that be ?

Comment: @soham : note added explaining "that's pretty much exactly how SQL was intended to work, it's a new mind set you will just have to get used to", but in a less flippant way :)

Comment: Many thanks, but I am not quite sure, the code is giving an error: It says, Operator Missing on 7th Line.

Comment: @soham : Try the edit. I've just been a bit more explicit about subtracting days, and removed the `-` character from the table aliases.

Comment: But Mytable.Date -1 should work as easily. I myself have used it. Not exactly in that way but like this #29-05-2011# +1 and its working perfectly

Comment: I dont understand where its wrong, til the first INNERJOIN I tried the code, its working perfectly, but when I give the second INNERJOIN , the error is showing up on the 7 line(again)

Comment: Access's Jet SQL requires explicitly ordering the INNER JOIN operations with the use of parentheses.

Comment: @mwolfe02 - Thanks, updated the answer, but feel free to edit it yourself, or make a copy answer that works :)